# Fetch IAP products from iTunes connect

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I am successfully able to implement IAP in my app. But products list is showing on the basis of mentioned products in configuration.storekit. How to get products from iTunes connect added in the account?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skproductsrequest

Comment: yes, already implemented this method. but it is not fetching products added on iTunes connect

Comment: That is the method you use.  Make sure you implement the invalid products delegate method and check for invalid product ids.   If you are asking can you just submit a request without providing a list of product identifiers then the answer is "no".